# Using Rails form helpers on non-existent methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, helper, actionview

Normally, when using form helpers in Rails, each field directly correlates to a method on the appropriate object.

However, I have a form (user signup) that needs to include fields that are not part of the user model itself (for instance, card details) but need to appear.

How can I build the form so that I can get the necessary fields, and validate them as I need to (so that it fits with all my other validations) without dirty-ing my user model?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "dirty-ing" your user model, but you can do this using the [attr_accessor method](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Module.html#M001681). This will allow you to create an attribute for the model that can be used for validations:

```
class Widget < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :confirmation_email
  validates_length_of :confirmation_email, :within => 1..10
end
```

To only run the validation at certain times, you could use an `:if` condition:

`validates_length_of :confirmation_email, :within => 1..10, :if => Proc.new { |widget| widget.creation_step > 2 }`

You can also use a class method, like: `:if => :payment_complete`. With these you should be able to achieve the functionality you want. As far as I know there isn't any more concise way.

Comment: Essentially I'm not building a form that directly correlates to the model in question.  For instance a signup form might incorporate some user properties, and some "throw away" properties (such as those you might fire at a CC gateway and then forget).

If I created attributes on my user model, I would always need to supply those properties for validations to pass whereas I only want to validate these items on this single form in this single location.

Comment: I've added information about the :if condition, which might be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Yehuda Katz has a [great explaination](http://yehudakatz.com/2010/01/10/activemodel-make-any-ruby-object-feel-like-activerecord/) of how you can use `ActiveModel` to make an arbitrary class compatible with Rails' form helpers. That only works if you're on Rails 3, though.

If you're not living on the bleeding edge, watch [Railscasts episode 193, "Tableless Model"](http://railscasts.com/episodes/193-tableless-model), which describes how you can create a class that quacks enough like `ActiveRecord::Base` that it works with `form_for`.